# sed not obeying \t or actual tab

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have seen this question a lot and I have tried everything I found and still I cannot get this working.

I am trying to add a new line in my virtualhost file for a script that manages aliases and have the new entry tabbed properly.

I have this line that adds the alias after I check it doesn't exist.

My final attempt: (still no tab.. I actually have 2 tabs in this one)

```
sed -i "/ServerAlias www.$account/a         $newAlias" "$VHOST_FILE"
```

Here's it again with a single tab

```
sed -i "/ServerAlias www.$account/a     $newAlias" "$VHOST_FILE"
```

I have also tried: (these all prefix with t instead of using a tab)

```
sed -i "/ServerAlias www.$account/a \t$newAlias" "$VHOST_FILE"
sed -i "/ServerAlias www.$account/a \\t$newAlias" "$VHOST_FILE"
sed -i "/ServerAlias www.$account/a\t$newAlias" "$VHOST_FILE"
sed -i "/ServerAlias www.$account/a\\t$newAlias" "$VHOST_FILE"
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks for any assistance

Comment: Have you tried putting in the tab as ctrl-V followed by ctrl-I?

Comment: Because you are using double quotes `"`, you will need triple backslashes \\\. The last line when changed to `sed -i "/ServerAlias www.$account/a\\\t$newAlias" "$VHOST_FILE"` should work.

Comment: This is why I always use single quotes for sed, even if it means hanging quoting styles mid-stream. e.g. since you have `$newAlias` etc. that need to be expanded, I would have `sed -i '/ServerAlias www.'"${account}"'/a\t'"${newAlias}" "${VHOST_FILE}"`  Yes, it can be a PITA but it is guaranteed to be correct, which I care more about especially in a utility script.  That's also why I use the `${}` form for variable expansion.  I'd rather be explicit so the intent is clear, and so surprise values don't break the script.

Comment: @StephenP I see what you are doing there. I think I like your way better. Will update my script. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close. The problem is that `\\` becomes a literal `\` in double quotes, so `\\t` and `\t` become the same thing.

Escape them to get the result you want:

```
sed -i "/ServerAlias www.$account/a \\\\t$newAlias" "$VHOST_FILE"
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly. I appreciate the explanation too

Answer (score 0):

In bash, you can use `$'\t'` to insert tab.

```
sed "/ServerAlias www.$account/a"$'\t'"$newAlias" "$VHOST_FILE"
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and still the same issue. the \\\t worked tho!

Comment: @Jeremy: Oh, it seems the `a` command needs a backslash: ``a\``.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to accomplish the same thing.  The best approach is to use stuff you can easily understand:

```
line=$'\t'"$newAlias" # a tab followed by contents of newAlias
sed "/ServerAlias www.$account/a $line" "$VHOST_FILE"
```

and then combine these (next time) once you've got a good grasp on what is going on.